# Rails NoMethodError on rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class CachedObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :value
  validates_presence_of :key
  validates_uniqueness_of :key
  serialize :value
end
```

And I'm running the following unit test:

```
class CachedObjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @cached_object = CachedObject.new
  end

  test "key should set" do
    @cached_object.key = 'test'
    assert @cached_object.save
  end

  test "value should set" do
    offer = new Offer

    @cached_object.value = offer
    assert @cached_object.save
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<CachedObjectTest:0x007fb1f1c82f08>
```

Which makes no sense to me.  CachedObject is a subclass of ActiveRecord, so it should have the new method defined.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please let me know if it helps ... If I am right would you give me the green check for the answered question ... otherwise let me know what I can do to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
  test "value should set" do
    offer = new Offer
```

it should be

```
  test "value should set" do
    offer = Offer.new
```

Comment: bah...damn my old habits!

Comment: I have been there. I started with Java. I hope that helps. Could you give me me the check for answered question... I am new and trying to build my score.